# Settings in Django run repeat when runserver

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-3.2

I don't know why my django app run settings/base.py 2 times. I think it would make my app slow down 
In my settings/base.py I printed

```
print('this is base_dir')
print(BASE_DIR)
```

output is:

```
this is base_dir
F:\7.Django\BLOG_PROJECT\src_blog
this is base_dir
F:\7.Django\BLOG_PROJECT\src_blog
```

This is my settings file:

> ```
>     ├── settings 
>     |     ├──__init__.py 
>     |     ├──base.py 
>     |     ├──dev.py 
>     |     ├──prod.py
> ```

and my `settings\__init__.py` file contain:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

if os.environ['ENV_SETTING'] =='prod':
   from .prod import *
else:
   from .dev import *

from .base import *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably related to the good old double thread spawning in Django. The way Django is setup it spawns two threads at the start, so one process is there to process requests and the other to watch if you changed any code so it can respawn the first one.

If you print the following in `settings.py`

```
import os
print(os.getpid())
```

You would see that it prints 2 different values. This is a standard django behaviour as far as I know.

Comment: Well! It did! Nice to know this! Thanks @AzyCrw4282!

Comment: @AzyCrw4282: Does this mean that this only occurs with the development server, and that on a production server, there is a single thread per worker?

Comment: @physicalattraction Good question. Though, I have no production means to test this, I would think so that it is the case.